# GCP VM stuck at login promote (from screenshots)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine

I would like to ask how to fix this issue, I created a VM from a snapshot backup but when I try to SSH from the console is showing error code 1006. I tried to check the Screenshot and its showing that one: [image: screenshot from the VM after starting up]

I tried to access it through serial port and that screen pops up also, but can bypassed with entering `root` .

SSH error:

[image]

The VM is not accessible through SSH or even the applications installed inside it, I think that the issue is that login promot.

EDIT:
i found out that the VM is not connected to the internet, somehow networking.service is not there :( .. how to solve this?
I tried to access the VM using serial port, and its unable to fetch any link when doing apt update .. also networking service is not found

Edit2:
Netwrok cards for the not working VM
[image]

Netwrok cards for a new working VM
[image]

Solved:
Final Edit:
After reviewing the boot log from `journalctl -b` I found out that cloud.init service haven't started correctly
`Failed to start Initial cloud-init job (pre-networking)`
, and needed to start it manually using serial port console with these commands:

```
    sudo cloud-init clean --logs
    sudo cloud-init init --local
    sudo cloud-init init
```

. After it started everything back to normal, in the original disk but for the snapshot the port 22 was somehow removed from the firewall so had to disable ufw before it backs to normal

Thanks John Hanley for helping

Comment: i found out that the VM is not connected to the internet, somehow networking.service is not there :( .. how to solve this?

Comment: What do you mean **not connected to the Internet**? Note: Edit your question and not via comments.

Comment: I tried to access the VM using serial port, and its unable to fetch any link when doing apt update .. also networking service is not found

Comment: 1) Verify that you are not out of free disk space on the root file system. 2) If you made the snapshot while the VM was running, the snapshot might be corrupt. Run a file system check **fsck** and verify. If it is corrupt, you must create a new snapshot from the original system while is it shutdown.

Comment: Thanks John,I have verified that the disk is only half full. Actually the case is that my VM was working fine until it was suspended by Google because they suspect I am doing crypto mining, so I still have the original disk and tried to create other VM attaching that disk to it but still the same issue, So I thought that older snapshots might be working but its excatly the same issue in both. I had this issue before and the workaround was that creating the VM in different project and that was working fine, but now either solution not working.

Comment: I think the issue is related to netwroking, but I am not really expert and couldn't figure out how to run it up again.

Comment: If you review the boot logs, you will find out what is wrong.

Comment: Could this be the issue? "Failed to start Initial cloud-init job (pre-networking)"

Comment: Yes, that will prevent your VM from running. What are the errors before that. Instead of using comments, put details **in your question**.

Comment: Thanks John, I think I figured it out, posted all the details in the original post.

Comment: Post your solution as an answer. This is a very interesting problem and solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Steps to reproduce the issue:**

- Creating an instance from an image or snapshot
- Creating new instance using a disk of previous instance

**Steps to solve this issue (SSH overconsole error code: 1006) in Google cloud**

Connected to the instance from the serial port and pass the login promote just by entering `root`, You will gain access to the machine command line. Then tried to troubleshoot and found that the machine is not connected to the internet, then reviewed boot log to figure out what was the issue.

After reviewing the boot log from `journalctl -b` I found out that cloud.init service haven't started correctly Failed to start Initial cloud-init job (pre-networking) , and needed to start it manually using serial port console with these commands:

```
sudo cloud-init clean --logs
sudo cloud-init init --local
sudo cloud-init init
```

After it started everything back to normal, in the original disk but for the snapshot the port 22 was somehow removed from the firewall so had to disable ufw before it backs to normal

**Update**: Every time the instance stopped and started it will have the same issue and need to repeat steps above to get it working again. I think it might be some bug in GCP instance creation with older disks that used to have other older instances (Need to try to replicate the issue with new instances to check if the issue is there as well)

Thanks John Hanley for helping